# I am using HTML snippet in to Highlight HTML and Javascript code in blog Joomla. but it's executed after saving it

Tags: joomla

while creating a article I want to show some HTML code as part of content, but after saving that article that particular snippet of HTML code get executed.

I am using joomla 1.5 | code citation extension for insert code in article. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off HTML stripping, or include it as a **Custom HTML Module**, and writing the position in the article with *load position*. to load the custom HTML you've put in the Module.  i.e.

```
{loadposition YourModulePosition}
```

Will load anything you place within a **Custom HTML Module**.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to turn off HTML stripping?

Comment: Go to Extensions > Plugin Manager > Editor - TinyMCE > Code cleanup on save

Answer (score 0):

The correct way should be to paste the code into the wysiwyg (design view, not raw code view) - as long as you have a decent editor the angle brackets *should* be converted to html entities and it should just work.

The built-in Geshi plugin - though a little dated - is usually all that is needed to make add colored highlighting. The plugin is a little dated but after inserting your code all you need to do to make it work is add:

```
<pre class="html"> ... </pre>
```

around your html. Chenge HTML to js, css, etc depending upon the code to be shown.